# How to inspect dialog created by right-click action in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In CKEditor, we have some plugins where we can right-click an element and a dialog is offered up. I need to inspect that menu. I know that Chrome Dev Tools allows you to force the element state with :hover, :active, :focus, :visited but as far as I can tell you cannot force a right click element state.

Is there any way to force the element state to be right clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Set a debug breakpoint during code that is executed while the menu is open. I believe that the command from the menu is executed before the menu is closed.

Otherwise, you can set a breakpoint for 'on dom manipulation'. See: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-mutation-events